# Magento 2.2.4 Unable to unserialize the value

Tags: magento2, database, json

I'm trying to import products with CSV programmatically and getting following error on update some product. I tracked down issue and only one thing which I know - all products returns JSON encoded string like `{"category_id":"393"}` but failed product returns this: `a:1:{s:11:"category_id";s:3:"257";}`. Where can I find this value in DB? Or how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Value `{s:11:"category_id";s:3:"257";}` was stored in column `metadata` in `url_rewrite` table. I changed value to `{"category_id":"257"}` and that's it.